# Example for latest Parcel + Vue

Tags: vue.js, parceljs

I have been trying to setup the latest version of Parcel (which supposedly supports Vue out of the box, without the need of additional plugins), but I keep getting all sort of errors.

I checked at https://github.com/parcel-bundler/examples/tree/master/Vue and I searched here and in Google, but I couldn't find a template/example showing how to build a Vue project with Parcel 1.7.x.

Where can I find an updated source of Parcel + Vue examples?

Comment: This might be good reference https://github.com/eddyerburgh/parcel-vuejs-template